# Perl program reads POST string length but won't read string

Tags: html, perl, post

I've recently migrated from a IIS host to an Apache host and my perl script is no longer working. I backed off to a simple fixed string POST. The perl script will read the correct value from $ENV{\'CONTENT_LENGTH\'}, but it won't read the string value.

The HTML file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Mail Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="This is a simple mail test. So far the mailtest.pl program won't even read any input.">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Email Us
        </h1>
        <!-- Starting out with a simple two value POST submit -->
        <form id="email_form" target="_blank" method="POST" action="cgi-bin/mailtest.pl">
            <input type="hidden" name="mytest" value="foo" >
            <input type="hidden" name="mytest2" value="bar" >
            <input type="submit" id="email_submit" value="Send Email" >
            <input type="reset" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The perl file, including a bunch of debug statements is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
print CGI::header();
# If you don't output a header, apache will not work.


print "<DOCTYPE! html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n";
print "<header>\n<title>\"Simple POST Test Result\"</title>\n";
print "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n</header>\n<body>\n";
print "<h1>Simple POST test.</h1>\n";

my $buffer = ''; # Raw POST data

print "<p>(1) Going to get the data.</p>\n";

&get_data;

print "<p>(8) Returned from get_data.</p>";
print "<p> I will only get this far if everything works</p>\n</body>\n</html>";

sub get_data {
 print '<p>(2) Getting the data.</p>';
 if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') {
   print "<p>(3) Verified: It's a POST request.</p>";
   print ("<p>(4) The length of the post data string as reported in ", '$ENV{\'CONTENT_LENGTH\'}', "is ", $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}, "</p>");
   print "<p>(5) The data should be \"mytest=foo&mytest2=bar\" so the length should be 22.";
   # Get the input
   print "<p>(6) If the POST data is read, it will be printed on the next line</p>";
   read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}) or die "POST data could not be read, why? Stopped ";
   print ("The buffer contained ", $buffer);
   print '<p>(7) Got the data.</p>';
  }
 else {
  print "<p3b> It wasn't a POST request so I will die soon.";
  die "The request method must be POST for this application. Stopped ";
  }

}
```

The html response is

> Simple POST test.
>   (1) Going to get the data.
>
> (2) Getting the data.
>
> (3) Verified: It's a POST request.
>
> (4) The length of the post data string as reported in $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'}is 22
>
> (5) The data should be "mytest=foo&mytest2=bar" so the length should be 22.
>
> (6) If the POST data is read, it will be printed on the next line

The error log contains nothing more than the die statement:

> AH01215: POST   data could not be read, why? Stopped  at mailtest.pl line 33.: /home/fffwweb/fffw.org/cgi-bin/mailtest.pl, referer: https://fffw.org/mailtest.html

The .htaccess file in all directories (granted that's overkill) is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
AddHandler cgi-script .pl
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/pdf pdf
```

I suspect my problem is something obvious, but I've spent three days trying to find it with no results, including chatting with web host tech support.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks,
Randy T

Comment: [read](https://perldoc.pl/functions/read) has multiple return possibilities. It might return 0 if there was nothing to read, or undef if there was an error, and in the latter case [$!](https://perldoc.pl/variables/%24!) is also set; both of these will fail the `or`. So you want to check which of these the return value falls into, and include `$!` in your die if the return was undef.

Comment: Forgot to mention file permissions are mailtest.html 644, .htaccess 644, cgi-bin/mailtest.pl 755, cgi-bin/.htaccess 755,

Comment: Why are you reading from STDIN at all? This is what the CGI module does for you, and even that is considered somewhat out of date.

Comment: I guess I need to take another look at CGI. I'm not real familiar with it. I didn't need it before I migrated. I started with a script I developed several years ago, and guess I haven't kept up. What replaces CGI? I'll have to check the host to see if it's there.

Comment: Reading POST parameters with CGI is done through the [param](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter) method (BUT make sure to read the warning there! and you may or many not have a new enough version to support multi_param). For how things are done now, see http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/11/modern-perl-cgi.html or [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives).

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out these two lines:

```
# use CGI;
# print CGI::header();
```

And replace them with a manually written header:

```
# Note: Fixed line endings
print "Content-type: text/html\015\012\015\012";
```

Then it will work as expected. But I don't recommend doing that. I recommend using CGI.pm as it expects to be used - and using its mechanisms for reading input parameters.

The problem is that CGI.pm does too much for you. Just by loading it, it will read all of your parameters - and that includes reading all of the data from `STDIN`. As CGI.pm has read the data from `STDIN`, there is no more data left for your code to read. The `CONTENT_LENGTH` environment variable is still set to its original value, but you can no longer expect to find that much data on the filehandle.

The solution is to not to try and re-read the data for yourself. Instead use the `param()` method to get the values of your input.

```
my $mytest  = CGI::param('mytest');
my $mytest2 = CGI::param('mytest2');
```

Comment: Also your manually written header is wrong; it must end in two CRLFs, not just two LFs, and this is not OS-dependent.

Comment: @Grinnz: I think "should" rather than "must". But Postel's Law applies, so I've fixed it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find too difficult to read your code. I took some liberty to clean up it.

Please see if you find the following style more appropriate

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
print CGI::header();
# If you don't output a header, apache will not work.

my $buffer = ''; # Raw POST data

print 
'<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en">
<header>
    <title>"Simple POST Test Result"</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</header>
<body>
    <h1>Simple POST test.</h1>
    <p>(1) Going to get the data.</p>
';

&get_data;

print '
    <p>(8) Returned from get_data.</p>
    <p> I will only get this far if everything works</p>
</body>
</html>
';

sub get_data {
 print '<p>(2) Getting the data.</p>';
 if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') {
   read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'})
        or die 'POST data could not be read, why? Stopped';

   print '
        <p>(3) Verified: It\'s a POST request.</p>
        <p>(4) The length of the post data string as reported in $ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH} is '
        . $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} . '
        </p>
        <p>(5) The data should be "mytest=foo&mytest2=bar" so the length should be 22.
        <p>(6) If the POST data is read, it will be printed on the next line</p>
        The buffer contained '
        . $buffer . '
        <p>(7) Got the data.</p>
        ';
  }
 else {
      print '<p3b> It wasn\'t a POST request so I will die soon.';
      die 'The request method must be POST for this application. Stopped';
  }
}
```

Also please see the following [webpage](https://www.perl.com/article/perl-and-cgi/)

Note: you excessively use double quotes without reason, they intended to be used for interpolation of variables. By using double quotes without reason you waste CPU cycles (perl still looks for variables in such strings to substitute their names to their values).